# How make with AS3 downloading MP3 files in the background mode and plays it?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I need help with AS3 make downloading MP3 files in the background mode. Man goes to my site and it will automatically load MP3 file on his computer and plays it. I read these examples here http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/URLLoader.html but do not know how to do it? Prompt what code and how to use it properly?

Comment: Check out [Sound](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/media/Sound.html) class, it plays mp3 in a stream mode

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can directly load a `Sound` object with an `URLRequest` instead of using a separate `Loader` or `URLLoader`. A code could look like this:

```
        // this code should reside in a function somewhere
        var request:URLRequest = new URLRequest("http://your.site.com/your.mp3"); 
        var sound:Sound = new Sound(request; 
        sound.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, completeHandler); 

    // this function should be at top level anyway
    private function completeHandler(event:Event):void 
    { 
        var loadedMP3:Sound = Sound(event.target); 
        if (loadedMP3) loadedMP3.play(); 
    }
```

Extra error handling is up to you.

Comment: Thank you very much. And if a lot of music, and it is located in the archive? How to download, unzip and run? Please with the example.

Comment: You'd better pack em into an SWF and download an SWF like this, then you can retrieve a nested sound by using child SWF's `applicationDomain` and then `getDefinitionByName()` with a known class name. Do you need an example of that? SWFs are deflated and also you can control how do you want to store sounds (bitrate, at the very least), so they are better than plain ZIP.